# how to generate confident intervals for predictions of hurdle models

Tags: prediction, confidence-interval, pscl

I'm using 'pscl' package to build hurdle models, in order to model the abundance of birds as a function of environmental variables.
I am interested in predicting the probability of occurrence and abundance in non-sampled areas, in order to generate population estimates for the species.
I was able to generate the models and predictions, but I am having difficulty producing credibility intervals for these estimates.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.